# Spring MVC Using Autowired Object Outside Controller Class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

i'm using Spring MVC for my project. Is it possible to use the same autowired object on another class?

I have two controllers, one for navigation and one for the operations.

this is my sample navigation controller:

```
@Controller
public class NavigationController {

    @Autowired
    private DepartmentDAO deptDao;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView panel() {
      ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("panel");
      Department dept = deptDao.getDept();
      mv.addObject("department",dept);
      return mv;
    }
}
```

then my operations controller:

```
 @Controller
 public class OperationController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/save.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView saveEvent(){
      ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("next");
      Event event = new EventCreator().createEvent();
      //some logic here
      return mv;
    }
 }
```

And this is my business delegate class :

```
public class EventCreator {
  public Event createEvent(){
   //logic here
   //I need to use the deptDao here.
  }
}
```

Thank You So Much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply Autowire `DepartmentDAO` in the `EventCreator` class, like how your autowired it in `NavigationController`  class. Make sure that you annotate the `EventCreator` class with `@Component` and include it in the package where component scanning is done so that spring will autowire the `DepartmentDao` in your `EventCreator` class.

```
@Component
public class EventCreator {

  @Autowired
  private DepartmentDAO deptDao;

  public Event createEvent(){
   //logic here
   //I need to use the deptDao here.

  //deptDao.getAllDepartments();

  }
}
```

Comment: Hi! I tried what you said but still i'm getting a nullpointerexception.

Comment: What is your package structure? In which package did you place the `EventCreator` class? How did you define component scanning ? Make sure that `EventCreator` class is  annotated with `@Component` and this class should be placed in a `base package` that you specified in the component scanning. You can post the full config and code if the issue is not resolved yet

Comment: Hi. fixed it. i forgot that i used new to create instance of EventCreator. now I @Autowired EventCreator in my operation controller. Thank you So much For the Help!

Answer (score 2):

You can @Autowired a spring bean object in another spring bean object

**Assumption**

> I assume that you have declared DepartmentDAO with @Repository 
>   annotation as you haven't include code of DepartmentDAO in your
>   question

**There are two ways to solve your problem** ,

> 1. one is very well explain by @TimeTravel  annotate EventCreator with
>      @Component with create spring bean and you can easy autowire
>      DepartmentDAO in the EventCreator class
> 2. As You have two controller class which  makes it spring beans as they are annotated with @Controller, what you can do you can  Autowire
>      departmentDAO in OperationController class and pass instance of
>      DepartmentDAO as argument in EventCreator class constructor

```
@Controller
public class OperationController {
@Autowired
private DepartmentDAO deptDao;

@RequestMapping(value = "/save.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView saveEvent(){
  ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("next");
  Event event = new EventCreator(deptDao).createEvent();
  //some logic here
  return mv;
  }
 }


public class EventCreator {

 private DepartmentDAO deptDao=null; 

 public EventCreator(DepartmentDAO deptDaoAsArg){
  deptDao=deptDaoAsArg;
 }

 public Event createEvent(){
 //logic here
 //I need to use the deptDao here.
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the help. I used the solution of TimeTravel. but still Thank you! :)

Comment: happy to help:) , its always coding decision what approach you want to use , I though I should provide you an alternate solution :)

Comment: Glad I found your answer, this is the only solution that worked for me